# Copy entire table into other table and change id

Tags: mysql, database, phpmyadmin

I want to copy all the rows from one table to another and change the ID if there is a duplicate.

I'm using phpmyadmin and tried the operations tab.

Copy table to (database.table):
Data Only
Add Auto Increment

This is the SQL it gives me:

```
INSERT INTO `wsuca2_dbwsuca2`.`cxtb4_menu` SELECT * FROM `wsuca2_dbwsuca2`.`j25_menu`
```

This is the error I'm getting:

> #1062 - Duplicate entry '0-0-root-*' for key 'idx_client_id_parent_id_alias_language'

Answer (score 0):

what you need is

`INSERT ...... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE`

also, "change the ID if there is a duplicate" is not enough it seems. Your table have a complex unique key of `client_id`,`parent_id`,`alias`,`language`.
both your table had an entry of with the above field set to 0-0-root-* so it throws a error because MySQL doesn't know how to handle it.

either

- update those entry manually before copying over
- use `INSERT ...... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` to specify how to update those entries when found.
- use `INSERT IGNORE` to ignore all duplicate entries (probably not what you want)

Answer (score 0):

Having Duplicate key error is clear notification that you did not use the same structure and keys in the both tables. So first recreate the structure:

```
DROP TABLE `wsuca2_dbwsuca2`.`cxtb4_menu`;
SHOW CREATE TABLE `wsuca2_dbwsuca2`.`j25_menu`; //old table structure
```

and paste the structure of j25_menu as structure od cxtb4_menu (change the name of the table). After that insert the data with your `INSERT` clause.